# html5 - Antialias when curves image in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to wrap an image around a mugs, I saw [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42486915/7103171) and follow it. But I still has a small question : Why edge in mugs doesn't antialiasing, I had to try many cases ( ex : imageSmoothingEnabled, use putImageData instead of drawImage,... ) but still doesn't work.

I want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjolU.jpg)

Not [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeqYS.png)

Can someone please finally provide an answer to this question. Sorry for my bad Eng :(