# How to "skew" a <div> to make it look as if it is applied to a cyclindrical object with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a website where you can order a cup with an image printed on it. You can compose the shown image from a few options and based on the selected inputs, we create a preview of the image that will be printed. After all, this could look like this:

[image: 2-dimensional picture displayed in front of a cup]

However, in real-life, the image wouldn't be flat, but it would follow the curvature of the cup. And look more like this:

[image]

Since the original image is composed of several layers of img-tags which are inside a div, I hoped that I could apply some CSS transformation on the div to "skew" the div to take this cylindrical shape.
Unfortunately, I haven't found a good soluction yet, therefore asking all of you :)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please post the code you have and explain using it what you've tried and the problems you encountered.

Comment: https://cssdeck.com/labs/wrap-image-in-3d-cylinder-2 Can't find a dupe in here though... There are a few for canvas, but I don't find one for CSS...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997344/wrap-an-image-around-a-cylindrical-object-in-html5-javascript This maybe? Has a couple of promising answers. Needs canvas though, not doable with pure CSS.

Comment: Thanks folks! There are really interesting ideas. I'll try them out and get back to you :)